# Add the default web site back to IIS 6.0

Tags: iis, iis-6

I unintentionally removed the default web site in the IIS manager.

Is there a way to bring it back or re-create it?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the folder/directory Web Sites , and select New -> Web Site.

If you want the exact same configuration, choose the directory to be `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot`

[image]